# Change font color in javascript timer

Tags: javascript, css, timer, colors

I have a very simple timer working within the DIV ID "clear", and I would like the font color of the div to change at exactly the one minute mark and again at the 2 minute mark.  It seems possible, but I can't figure it out.

```
var ho1 = document.getElementsByTagName('ho1')[0],
clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
t;

function add() {
seconds++;
if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
}

ho1.textContent = (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

timer();
}
function timer() {
t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();
```

Can anyone help me?  The color is difined in the DIV's style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HoeInside your if condition where you check for `seconds`

```
if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    // check for minutes
    minutes++;
    if(minutes===1) ho1.style.color = "red";
    if(minutes===2)  ho1.style.color = "green";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to change to a different color after 2 minutes?  I want to change color on a minute by minute basis.  With different colors.  For example: 1 min= yellow. 3 min = red.

Comment: Yes, check for minute and change

Comment: Updated answer with checking minutes

Comment: If you want exactly for 1 minute and 2 minutes. you need to check for hour as well to be 0. Just wanted to let you know. In your current code, you don't have anything related to hours so i skipped it

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery and Switch-case:

```
window.scount = 0;

function changeColor() {
  switch (window.scount) {
    case 0:
        timer('white')
        break
    case 1:
       timer('red')
       timer()
       break
    case 2:
       timer('green')
       break
    default:
       console.log('end')
       break
  }
}

function timer(color) {
  $('#clear').css('background-color', color)
  setTimeout(changeColor, 1000);
  window.scount = window.scount + 1;
}
timer(black);
```

Comment: This example assumes jQuery, which I think it is reasonable to assume from OP's code isn't included.

Comment: @Legendary Was it really in SO? LOL

Comment: @mohamedrias there are was Dark times, my friend

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I am not using jQuery.  Still, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @user3283304 glad for u, but maybe once, in 5 years, someone has task like u, but he use jQuery, and he can google my ans! : D